# Не получается отправить данные из формы на сервер в .NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, .net, mvc, razor

У меня есть форма на cshtml:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("DataCheck", "Home"))
        {
            <div class="inputGroup inputGroup1">

                <label id="adminLogin" for="adminlogin">Логин</label>
                @Html.TextBox("adminlogin", null, new { @class = "login" })


                <span class="indicator"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="inputGroup inputGroup2">
                <label id="adminPassword" for="adminpassword">Пароль</label>
                @Html.Password("adminpassword", null, new { @class = "password" })

            </div>
            <div class="inputGroup inputGroup3">
                <input type="submit" id="log_in" value="Войти" />
                <p> @ViewBag.Text </p>
            </div>

            <div class="login-close-popup js-login-close-campaign"></div>

        }
```

Вот метод "DataCheck" в контроллере:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DataCheck (string adminlogin, string adminpassword)
    {
        if(adminlogin == "Kate_adm" && adminpassword == "1234520")
        {
            return View("Admin_Page");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Text = "Неверно введены данные.";
            return View("Index");
        } 

    }
```

В результате, какие бы данные не были введены в форму, страница просто перезагружается, а в адресной строке появляется что-то подобное:

```
http://localhost:49477/?adminlogin=Kate_adm&adminpassword=1234520
```

Что не так с этим кодом?

Comment: И что вам не нравится? Вы какое-то другое поведение ожидали? У вас между прочим код делает именно то, что вы ему попросили.

Comment: Возможно вы хотите при проверке одно из условий сделать редирект на другую страницу. return Redirect вместо return View